# How to add GET parameters to django-tables2 LinkColumn

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to set GET parameters on a `LinkColumn` based on Accessors with `django-tables2`.

Let's say:

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    url(r'^rqGET$', views.rqGET, name='rqGET'),
...
]
```

## views.py

```
def rqGET(request):
    #... do something with request.GET
```

## tables.py

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    id = LinkColumn('rqGet',text='Link') # do something with Accessors to make a GET string, maybe ?id=A('pk')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel #(has field 'id')
```

I want to use reverse to get the correct url, then construct the GET parameter string. For example `/rqGET?id=1` ('1' would be different in each row).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really how Accessors work in django-tables2. Django-tables2 uses django's [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to generate urls. If you want `reverse` to be able to generate the url, you need to define the parameters in your urls, which will be passed as arguments to your view function:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
...
    url(r'^rqGET/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.rqGET, name='rqGET'),
...
]

# views.py
def rqGET(request, id):
    # do something with request/id.
```

If you don't want to change the way your url is formatted, you can use a custom `render_` function on your `MyTable` like this:

```
# tables.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    id = LinkColumn('rqGet', text='Link') # do something with Accessors to make a GET string, maybe ?id=A('pk')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def render_id(self, record):
        url = reverse('rqGET')
        return format_html('<a href="{}?id={}">{}</a>', url, record.id, 'Link')
```

This will render a link with format `/rqGET/?id=<id>`.